# Prior to reboot, path to new HD was correct, post reboot, name has changed

Tags: mount, hard-drive, fstab

I installed a new hard drive for the bulk of my storage and followed some instructions on how to add it to the machine. Prior to reboot, everything worked fine using `/media/Storage`, however post reboot it is /mnt/c2375920-53d5-4d43-b391-7de83d698417 and I fear I didn't permanently mount it or something along those lines. fstab below, last item on it is the drive I'm working on.:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=8a636df8-4aea-4eb8-8e44-9dd5548b4db0 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=ED05-A840  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=472e2d29-aa2c-41ee-ab69-f6a89cc6df26 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/c2375920-53d5-4d43-b391-7de83d698417 /mnt/c2375920-53d5-4d43-b391-7de83d698417 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

I wrote some aliases using /media/Storage that no longer work because of this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's also better to use `UUID=` instead of `/dev/disk/by-uuid`, but that's not relevant here. Secondly, `/media` is meant for non-permanent drives (USBs, etc.). Instead, you *should use `/mnt/Storage`, but it really doesn't matter in the grand scheme of things

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will do that way instead. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/media is for removable storage, but you can mount it there.

In your `fstab` the mount point is set to where you do not want it mounting. At boot, drives will be set according to what is in `fstab`

`/dev/disk/by-uuid/c2375920-53d5-4d43-b391-7de83d698417` **>>>** `/mnt/c2375920-53d5-4d43-b391-7de83d698417`

The first part is the drive `<file system>` , the second part is the mount location `<mount point>` . You can change that to any folder that exists on your system.

If the folder doesn't exist `mkdir /media/Storage` then  `sudo umount /mnt/c2375920-53d5-4d43-b391-7de83d698417`, then edit  `fstab` then do `sudo mount /media/Storage`

Comment: So to permanently set this to /mnt/Storage rather than media, 

`mkdir /mnt/Storage` > `sudo umount /mnt/c2375920-53d5-4d43-b391-7de83d698417`, and change fstab from:

`/dev/disk/by-uuid/c2375920-53d5-4d43-b391-7de83d698417 /mnt/c2375920-53d5-4d43-b391-7de83d698417 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0` 
to

`/dev/disk/by-uuid/c2375920-53d5-4d43-b391-7de83d698417 /mnt/Storage auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0`
then

`sudo mount -a`

Does that seem right?

Comment: I did what was written above and after a reboot everything worked great! Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted it out.